# Where to install curator? Data nodes or Master node?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

Do we need to install curator on every data node or only the master node to delete indices older than a month.

Answer (score 1):

Curator does not actually even need to be installed on one of your cluster nodes.  Curator only requires access to a client node to work.

There are some cases where, with configuration management utilities like Puppet, Chef, or Ansible, you want each node to be consistent, so Curator is installed on each node, with every command used.  In cases like this, you would use the --master-only flag with your Curator command-line, which prevents execution on any node but the *elected* master node.